# asp bootstrap-select not working

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

asp .net 4.0 Use bootstrap-select When running the code behind, the dropdown list is not displayed. But If not running the code behind, the dropdown list is displayed.

page.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker" OnSelectedIndexChange="ddlChange" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

page.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddl.Style["display"] = "inline";
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectString);
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select name from customer", sqlCon);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    ddl.DataSource = dt;
    ddl.DataValueField = "name";
    ddl.DataTextField = "name";
    ddl.DataBind();
    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

How do I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: where have you written this code of binding DDL.?? is it directly insode page load??

Comment: Written in page_load

Comment: could you post your entire page_load event in the question.

Comment: when access to page.aspx, Will load data from the database into the dropdown. If there is no data, hide the dropdown. (View the code at the answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Seeing from your comment you could use below:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
    ddl.Visible= true;
}
else
{
   ddl.Visible= false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ddl.Style["display"] = "inline";
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectString);
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select name from customer", sqlCon);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    ddl.DataSource = dt;
    ddl.DataValueField = "name";
    ddl.DataTextField = "name";
    ddl.DataBind();
    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

Comment: You can make changes to your question by clicking the edit button below the question. Don't post edits as an answer. I have fixed it for you. Please delete this answer.